# Как оплатить Google Play Console в России без Visa и MasterCard?

Tags: unity3d, google-play

Сделал игру на Unity, но когда дело дошло до регистрации аккаунта Google разработчика и его оплаты в 25$, то Visa и MasterCard не принимает. Есть ли какие-нибудь другие способы оплатить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можешь обратится к издателям. Они за место тебя выложат твои игру. Могут брать за это деньги, либо какой-то процент от донатов

Comment: Либо попросить знакомого из другой страны оплатить

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: можешь подсказать хотя бы пару издателей для небольших мобильных игр? Такие вообще существуют?